# I cannot type left open bracket into buffer

Tags: key-bindings, yasnippet, use-package

I have a very weird problem, I cannot type left open bracket character (`[`) into any buffer. Bracket itself is recognized when I:

- type anywhere outside emacs
- type in minibuffer
- use it as part of command (`[[` in evil normal state or `C-c [` in reftex work as expected)
- launch `emacs -Q`, then it works in buffers

After typing `[` it looks like this:

[image: left bracket as prefix]

When I try to describe `[` with `C-h k`, it's treated as prefix, not as all the other chars (which do `self-insert-command)`.

I can't manually bind inserting `[` to `[`, it's not recognized. My current workaround is like this:

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") (kbd "C-x 8 RET L S B R RET"))`

This interactively selects `"LEFT SQUARE BRACKET"` in `C-x 8 RET` (insert char) command in my ivy-flx, but it's slower and annoying.

I'm not on macbook, as they seem to have related problems (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376863/unable-to-type-braces-and-square-braces-in-emacs), I'm on Arch Linux, with emacs 25.2.1.

After turning evil-mode off the problem persists, so I guess that's not that.

My config is here: https://pastebin.com/8FLSkbAA.

Any feedback really appreciated!

Comment: You already know it works fine when you start without your `init` file (`emacs -Q`).  So it's something in your `init` file.  You need to bisect it recursively to isolate the problem.

Comment: If you hit `[ <f1>` it should show you what `[` is a prefix of, which might be helpful.

Comment: @Dan thanks, I started disabling minor modes and soon found out that yasnippet is the culprit here. @npostavs amazing! I had this binding overriden by `which-key`, but once I got it working it gave me the yasnippet answer right away! http://imgur.com/a/aXX7F
now the question is how to fix it, but now I'm much closer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT and final answer**: Okay, so thanks to the @npostavs (can't thank you enough :D) I can finally tell the real problem was me not understanding the use-package binding syntax, we can have either

- `("C-c x" . some-fun)` "string syntax" or
- `([tab] . some-fun)` "vector syntax" (mainly for special characters)

Syntax is based on [this part of manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html).

I was mixing both and in the process use-package interpreted my shortcut `"[backtab]"` as literal sequence of 9 characters `[` `b` `a` `c` `k` `t` `a` `b` `]`, which was quite far from what I was trying to do :D.

As a bonus, working code (can be launched in `emacs -Q` and `M-x eval-buffer` to properly rebind yasnippet `tab` and `shift tab` using `use-package`.

```
(package-initialize)
(require 'use-package)
(require 'bind-key)
(use-package yasnippet
  :bind
  (:map yas-minor-mode-map
    ([tab] . nil)
    ([?\t] . nil)
    ([(shift tab)] . nil)
    ([backtab] . nil)
    ("C-c r" . yas-prev-field)
    ("C-c t" . yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand)
    :map yas-keymap
    ([tab] . nil)
    ([?\t] . nil)
    ([(shift tab)] . nil)
    ([backtab] . nil)
    ("C-c r" . yas-prev-field)
    ("C-c t" . yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand)))

(yas-minor-mode 1)
```

**Initial post:**

Okay, the reason was in yasnippet's interpretation of this part of my config:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :diminish yas-minor-mode
  :bind
  (:map yas-minor-mode-map
  ("<tab>" . yas-expand)
  ("TAB" . yas-expand)
  ;; ("[(shift tab)]" . nil) ;; THIS made "[" act like prefix
  ;; ("[backtab]" . nil) ;; THIS made "[" act like prefix
  ("<S-iso-lefttab>" . yas-prev-field))
  :config
  (yas-global-mode 1))
```

My keyboard on `Shift+Tab` is understood by emacs as `<S-iso-lefttab>` ([as described in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692879/emacs24-backtab-is-undefined-how-to-define-this-shortcut-key)), so, according to [yasnippet faq](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/doc/faq.org#how-to-i-use-alternative-keys-ie-not-tab) I tried to unbind other keys with notation they provided, but well, that bug was really unexpected. Maybe a bug with interaction with use-package's bind macro? I'll try to provide minimal config to reproduce it, and file an issue on yasnippet.

Huge thanks to @npostavs for suggestion that if `[` acted as prefix, hitting `[ <f1>` allows to quickly find what follows after it, in my case: 
[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is a misuse of `use-package`'s `:bind` form, you mixed the string `kbd` notation with vector notation for keybindings. See [(emacs) Init Rebinding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html).

Comment: I'm not convinced that you need to file an issue with `use-package` or `yasnippet`, unless one of them provided the faulty code.  What would you have them fix?  Looking that the yasnippet FAQ, I don't see any problem with what they did.

Comment: @nispio you're right, the fault was on my side, as npostavs correctly saw. I've updated the answer, thanks for help and your time!